# Power BI Running Total DAX Calculation

Tags: powerbi, dax, cumulative-sum

I am trying to create a custom column measure in Power BI that does not appear to be working. I have tried the below formula but I am looking for this measure to calculate for each individual row a running total starting with the date column and going back a year. I can only get this to work to pull an entire running total for all columns.

```
Running Total =
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( DT[NetIncome] ),
    ALL ( DT ),
    DT[Date] <= EARLIER ( DT[1YearAgo] )
)
```

Comment: Please make this question reproducible to others by providing some sample data of your DT table, no screenshot! Otherwise no one can help you.

Comment: Have you tried using MIN, Also add sample data and required output.